# I am getting IOException error and try-catch does not save me

Tags: java, exception

I am getting IOException error saying:

> unreported exception IOException, must be caught or declared to be thrown

I have searched for answers but none of them was helpful so that is why I got to ask. Debugger indicates this line:

```
public static Item item = new Item();
```

Just the right side gives error. I tried to use try catch but it only led to more errors. I also tried to take that line inside Menu class but errors occur agian. I am pretty sure I am missing something so simple but desperate to ask you guys.

```
package proje;

public class Home extends Item  {
    public static Item item = new Item();
}
```

Comment: Well, I would assume that the `Item` constructor can throw a `IOException`, which can't be dealt with when initialising instance fields, you'd have to do in the constructor of `Home`, but since `Home` extends `Item` that raises a bunch of new questions.  My first recommendation is, learning to live without `static`, is not helping in this context

Comment: Unrelated: learn clean code. Your poor method is doing way too many things!

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: hmm, pretty drastic editing undertaken by @talex

Comment: @AndrewThompson that 'talex' guy edited my answer deleting unnecessary pieces of code

Comment: @ScaryWombat yep, but it was unrelated.

Comment: But neither edits make it a [mcve], so we'll just guess at the solution instead

Answer (score 0):

You have to create this object in static block or instance block because you are creating static object and your Item class constructor throwing IOException that's why you have to handle it in try catch.
see example.

```
public static Item item = null ;
static 
{
    try 
    {
        item = new Item();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

or

{
    try 
    {
        item = new Item();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```